# Scala: merge concurrent HTTP requests

Tags: scala, concurrency, http-post, kafka-consumer-api

To reduce the number of requests per second, how could multiple, concurrent (POST) requests be safely merged into a single, batched request?

```
// for instance, does a thread-unsafe batched POST risk data loss/dupes?
val data = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[String]()

// simple kafka-client reading from multiple partitions
kafkaConsumerIter.foreach { concurrentIncomingData  =>
    data.enqueue(s"request data: $concurrentIncomingData")
    if (data.length % 1000 == 0) {
        val postData = data.dequeueAll(_ => true).mkString

        ...post a batch of roughly ~1000 in a single request...
    }
}
```

This method of batching accomplishes reducing requests per second while keeping the queue size reasonably low for it's scale (which isn't expected to grow at all), but does this approach run the risk of data loss or duplication?

Would an implementation using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` be safer? If so, what is the safest way to `dequeue` the entire (all) ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: Is using http2 or Akka an option?

Comment: amount of work for each request does not change, does it? Then throughput will not increase. The latency definitely would increase, as most messages would wait the batch to be completed.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but [in my application there is significant performance improvements by sending multiple requests in a single POST](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/guides/writing_data/#writing-multiple-points). I am using Spray for asynchronous http pipelines.